# How to add my logic as per my understanding factorial?

Tags: java, logic, factorial

I am trying to calculate the factorial, like take an example 5!

5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120 right

20 * 3 * 2 * 1

60 * 2 * 1

120 * 1

120

How to apply this logic in code? I tried this:

```
int sum = 0;
int num = 5;
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
{
  sum = num * (num - 1)
```

I know this is wrong for for loop but if I use this I get the 5 * 4 = 20 for the first iteration

Or:

```
sum = 1;
sum = sum * (num - i)
```

It gives like this:

1 = 1 * 4 = 4;

4 = 4 * 3 = 12;

12 = 12 * 2 = 24

24 = 24 * 1 = 24

Comment: Figure out what you want `sum` (a bad name, btw) to be in terms of `i`.  That should tell you how to initialize them, what needs to happen to `sum` when you change `i`, and how to tell when your loop is done.

Comment: `sum` should be called `product` and should be initialized to 1 (the multiplicative identity), not 0 (the additive identity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private int factorial(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n < 0");
    }

    int sum = 1;
    for (int i = n; i > 1; i--) {
        sum *= i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved pretty easily with recursion. Essentially, n! is the same as n * (n-1)!. You can use this information to build a simple recursive function to solve the problem. Ex:

```
public static int factorial(int n) {
    if(n == 1) return 1;
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

The base case is when n = 1, since 1! is 1.

Comment: What about `0!`?  Your code would StackOverflow with it, when the result should be `1`

Comment: I'm a big fan of recursion, but you make it sound like this is easier than an iterative solution, which it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it.  Since factorials can get quite large,
I'm using a `BigInteger`.  And to expedite computations I am saving previously computed factorials.  This is known as `memoization`.

```
System.out.println(fact(1));
System.out.println(fact(0));
System.out.println(fact(15));
System.out.println(fact(20));
System.out.println(fact(22));
System.out.println(fact(15));
System.out.println(fact(21));
System.out.println(fact(22));
System.out.println(fact(23));
```

prints

```
1
1
1307674368000
2432902008176640000
1124000727777607680000
1307674368000
51090942171709440000
1124000727777607680000
25852016738884976640000
```

Nothing too elaborate here

- declare a static list to hold previously computed factorials.
- check if n >= 0
- see if the the factorial has been computed.  If so return it.
- otherwise, start with the last computed and continue.
- save each subequently computed factorial
- when finished, return the result.

```
static List<BigInteger> computedFactorials =
        new ArrayList<>(List.of(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger.ONE));
    
public static BigInteger fact(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be  >= 0");
    }
    
    if (computedFactorials.size() > n) {
//      System.out.println("successful lookup");
        return computedFactorials.get(n);
    }
    int k = computedFactorials.size() - 1;
    BigInteger fact = computedFactorials.get(k);
    for (int i = k + 1; i <= n; i++) {
        fact = fact.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
//      System.out.println("i = " + i + ", fact = " + fact);
        computedFactorials.add(fact);
    }
    return fact;
}
```

If you want to see the method in action, just uncomment the two print statements. The downside here is that the list needs to be recomputed each time the program is run.  It would be better to save this to a data base on a serialized list.  But it may also be overkill based on your specific needs.  It could easily be retrofitted to use `ints` or `longs`.